# In [*] print(5) вот так выглядит строка и ничего не выводит хотя должен выводить цифру 5

Tags: input, print

```
name = input()
Anton
print('Hello', name)
```

не выводит принт помогите!!!

Comment: учись читать сообщения об ошибках

Answer (score 1):

```
name = input('Введите имя: ')

print('Hello', name)
```